# How to achieve the same as build.gradle in Eclipse(with Android Developer Tools)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am a Java novice and am trying out the Google Endpoints with Python backend(module) for web app and Java for Android coding. I am following the [official Google tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/getstarted/clients/android/configure#configuring_the_project).

On the above link, the tutorial describes the setup using Android Studio and asks us to replace the build.gradle file with the given content. But in eclipse(with ADT), I could not find the build.gradle file itself. On googling, I found that there is a Gradle plugin available for Eclipse.

What is the recommended way to develop Google Cloud Endpoints based Android App: using Android Studio or Eclipse as editor(in terms of ease)? 
If Eclipse is an equally good option for above question(which I believe should be the case), how do I solve this grade.build problem?

If there are any other updated tutorials for the same, please mention them as well. Appreciate your time and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing Sir,
If you built via Eclipse you could skip the build.gradle part

In conclusion,
you can skip from **Configuring the Project** and go to the next page
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/getstarted/clients/android/create_app

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it really that simple :) I would check it and update you(and accept the answer). Thanks again

Comment: If you never use Google Play Lib before, please see this first
http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Install